# How do I find which row is using the most space in my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 database which users can attach files to (mainly Jpgs) however the table size is 130mb with only 20 records.

I need to find out which row is using the most amount of space.

The data is stored as `varbinary`

Thanks

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes you are correct. Bad Googling Skills for this question. Thank you

Comment: I'd also set a max file size policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DATALENGTH` to get the length of the `varbinary` column:

```
SELECT Id, Name, DATALENGTH(BinaryColumn)
FROM dbo.YourTable
ORDER BY DATALENGTH(BinaryColumn) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. How can I convert this to kb / mb - * 8 / 1024?

`select ((DATALENGTH(filecontent) * 8) / 1024) fg, *  from Attachments
order by fg desc`

Comment: @SCramphorn: `DATALENGTH` returns **number of bytes** - so just divide by 1024 (or 1024.0, if you want to avoid integer division) or by (1024*1024) etc.